# When flagging a question that is already closed as duplicate, error message is incorrect

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions, error-message

I was viewing a  question for a while, then decided to flag it.

When clicking the flag link, I got:

> [image]

In words, for sake of search:

> This question has been put on-hold since you loaded the page - please refresh and try your action again.

Fair enough, I refreshed the page. However the question was closed **as a duplicate**, not put on hold.

Since this isn't the same thing, can the message please be corrected in case it's closed as duplicate?